# Liqp (liquid template engine for java) accessing field of object

Tags: java, liquid

I'm trying to use [Liqp](https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp) to parse a string template but I am unable to access the fields of the objects that I put in the context....

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
model.put("test", new Test("Value of field"));
Template template = Template.parse("Something {{test.field}}");
String output = template.render(model);
```

The field is public, has getters and every possible way of enabling access.

The ouptut of the above code is: "Something "

Answer (score 1):

You were expected to convert the `Test` instance into JSON or a `Map`. But since `0.7.3-SNAPSHOT`, that is no longer necessary: https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp/pull/67